# How to let the user input as many lines of input as they want until they input the "stop" word in Python?

Tags: python, input, line

Say that I'm asking the user to input lines from a book or whatever. I don't know how many lines they will decide to input though. How would you let them input as many lines as they want until they input a secret word, "blueblue" for example. That's the code i've got so far.

```
while (blueblue == false):
line1 = input()
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Hey, after using Owen's code i'm having a problem with reading and outputing some info. I'd like to ask it here instead of opening another question. Here's my code now:

```
lines = []
current_line = input()
while current_line != "blueblue":
    lines.append(current_line)
    current_line = input()
print (lines)
ints_list = []
for line_ in lines:
    for letter in line:
        if (letter == "0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"):
             print ("hueheuheuehheuue")
```

Now Say that user input is :

```
1 hello my name
is cmput 3.4
```

It will just print "huehueheuheu" the number of characters there are in the while input.
I've tried the number without brackets and still deson't work, i've even tried "or".
Please help.

Comment: You want to print only the numbers? I dont understand the updated new  question properly. Please specify expected output as well.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple and neat way to do this.

**Python 3**

```
for inputString in iter(input, "blueblue"):
    print (inputString)
```

**Python 2**

```
for inputString in iter(raw_input, "blueblue"):
    print (inputString)
```

**EDIT:** Looks like you want to print `hueheuheuehheuue` for every number you encounter. It can be done like this.

```
for inputString in iter(raw_input, "blueblue"):
    for inputChar in inputString:
        if inputChar.isdigit():
            print ("hueheuheuehheuue")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lines = []
current_line = input()
while current_line != "blueblue":
    lines.append(current_line)
    current_line = input()

# Process lines
```

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty much what you told it to do.

You currently loop through every letter- if it is a number, you print "huehue", if it isn't, you don't do anything.

Therefore, if your input is >  in 3 or 4

your program thinks

```
i > do nothing
n > do nothing
3 > huehue
o > do nothing
r > do nothing
4 > huehue
```

Since you didn't say what you were *trying* to do, that is as far as I can go!

EDIT - That is the desired output?
I would have expected it to work except for your typos, but when I loaded it up I got the same thing you did.  I did it the way I usually do and it did work, but I cannot tell you why yours didn't.
In that case, try this...

```
lines = []
current_line = str(raw_input(">"))
while current_line != "blueblue":
    lines.append(current_line)
    current_line = str(raw_input(">"))
print (lines)
numbers = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
for line in lines:
    for letter in line:
        if letter in numbers:
            print ("hueheuheuehheuue")
```

Immediately after typing that, I realized the problem.

if (letter == "0, "1" ...
is checking if letter = 1, and then it's checking "1", which will always be true.  Moving the parentheses like

if letter == ("0", "1", ...

fixes the problem as well.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do but it writes "hueheuehuehue" way too many times. It writes it for anything, not only numbers...

Comment: @dkentre What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: For each digit in the input i wanna output huehueheue once.